# JavaFX TextArea doesn't display all lines of text with scrollbar

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextArea, and when the amount of text exceeds the capacity of the visable TextArea, the scrollbar appears and works as normal... to a degree.

My issue is that after a certain amount of text, the text cuts off and the scrollbar doesn't scroll any further. If I delete earlier lines, new lines that have been cut off do appear at the bottom.

I've been scouring for a while and have yet to figure out how, or why this is happening.

I'm using Scenebuilder, should that make a difference.

Relevent FXML Code:

```
 <TextArea fx:id="diaryTF" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="491.0" promptText="Write Entry Here..." wrapText="true" />
```

---

CSS Code:

```
.text-field{

-fx-font-family: 'Kiwi3';
-fx-background-color: null;

}
.text-area{
    -fx-font-family: 'Kiwi3';
    -fx-background-color: none;  
    -fx-border-color: none;
    -fx-font-size: 15;    
}
.text-area .text {
    -fx-line-spacing: 10px;
}
.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.text-area .scroll-pane .viewport{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.text-area .scroll-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

I tried checking to see if there was some constraint I added without realising, or if the TextArea has an autocapacity that I can override, but I couldn't find anything.

I found a question on here about a similar issue, but their scroll didn't work at all, and their fix didn't work for me. Yet again, the scroll works, just for some reason it doesn't go the entire way to the end of the text.
Additionally, this issue is not related at all to loading text files within a TextArea.

Comment: Please remove the excessive whitespace from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)).

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: These aren't duplicates, as my texts aren't really long, and I'm not using text files either. Thanks for the suggestion, it will be useful in my project later. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect this clarification.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who might be having the same issue as me in the future,
I removed the following from my CSS:

```
.text-area .text {
    -fx-line-spacing: 10px;
}
```

and it seems to be working now. I'll have to see if there's a way to handle this without taking it out altogether, but that seems to be what was messing it up.

Comment: If the scrolling behavior is messing up because of a non-default line spacing, you might consider [submitting a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/), assuming one [doesn't already exist](https://bugs.openjdk.org/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8299238?filter=allopenissues). If you do submit a bug report, make sure you isolate the issue entirely (e.g., is CSS required to reproduce the bug?) and provide a [mre].